# ExUnit own case

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to create my own AccountCase, in which I would create a user and session, and use it in my tests. I looked at ConnCase, and try to do so:

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.AccountHelpers do
  using(opts) do
    user_attrs = Keyword.get(opts, :attrs, %{login: "test@gmail.com", password: "123456", locale: "en"})
    quote do
      def fixture(:user) do
        {:ok, %{session: session, user: user}} = MyApp.Sessions.register_user(user_attrs)
        ....
        {:ok, %{user: user, session: session}}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In the test file, I do so:

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.V1.CategoryControllerTest do
    use MyAppWeb.ConnCase
    use MyAppWeb.AccountHelpers
...
end
```

but when I run the test, I get an error

```
** (CompileError) test/myapp_web/controllers/v1/category_controller_test.exs:3: module MyAppWeb.AccountHelpers is not loaded and could not be found
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.use/1
```

How correctly to create the case?

Comment: In which file is `MyAppWeb.AccountHelpers` defined?

Comment: ../myapp/test/account_helpers.ex

Comment: I moved it to ../myapp/test/support/, thanks! @Dogbert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `test` environment in Phoenix, the only `.ex` files compiled and therefore available in your test `.exs` files are the ones in `lib/` and `test/support/` (see the definition of `elixirc_paths` in your `mix.exs`). Your `.ex` file is in `test/` which won't be compiled, which means the modules defined there are not available to your tests and you get the "could not be found" error. The solution is to move the `.ex` file to `test/support/`.